# How AJAX requests work on Android 2.0 vs. Android 2.2

Tags: jquery, android, ajax

I'm testing out a web page on the Android 2.0 and 2.2 emulators, and the jQuery.ajax() requests that the app makes have slightly different behaviors regarding HTTP Authentication Headers.

The server I'm making requests to requires basic authentication, and the ajax requests in 2.2 send the proper auth header. In 2.0, I am debugging with Fiddler, and it seems that the requests do not include the auth header, and the server rejects the request with a 401.2 error. I don't think it matters, but the server is running IIS 7.

One interesting thing I noticed while debugging the web requests is that Android 2.2 makes two requests for each resource, whether or not it's an XHR. One does not contain the Auth header, and the second one does. In 2.0, it seems to make 2 requests for everything but XHR's:

Here is the 2.2 header for the first XHR:

```
GET http://192.168.1.111/sonar/mobileweb/sonar/views/week/init.ejs HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.111
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Referer: http://192.168.1.111/sonar/mobileweb/sonar/sonar.html
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; sdk Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Accept: text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
```

The 2.2 header for the second XHR:

```
GET http://192.168.1.111/sonar/mobileweb/sonar/views/week/init.ejs HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.111
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Referer: http://192.168.1.111/sonar/mobileweb/sonar/sonar.html
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; sdk Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Authorization: Basic cGFyaXZlZGFcZGF2aWQubW9ycmlzOjIzbkx2ZWxsbGw=
Accept: text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
```

And the 2.0 header:

```
GET http://192.168.1.111/app/views/week/init.ejs HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.111
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Referer: http://192.168.1.111/app/app.html
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; sdk Build/ECLAIR) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17
Accept: text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
```

Has anyone experienced this behavior before? It is basically causing my app to not work at all in version 2.0. Version 2.1 seems to act the same as 2.0.

Let me know if you have any ideas, thanks for your help,

Dave

Comment: I found a ticket on the android project that seems to be related:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3497

Can anyone help me verify whether this issue is specific to 2.1 and below, and possibly help me resolve the issue from my end? Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

yes, i have the exact same problem, and was able to work around it by writing the auth data to a cookie at first login, then add this to the ajax request in each login in 2.0 but in 2.1 for some reason this doesn't work when it is tried quickly, but if you pause between steps of ajax requests then it works.  Also a browser refresh seems to then carry the authentication data...

Comment: interesting. I might try adding a pause in. I have a suspicion that it has something to do with making ajax requests synchronous vs. asynchronous. The request in question in my application is a synchronous request, so I am wondering if that is part of the problem. I tried injecting auth headers in manually and still couldn't get it to work. I will try putting in a delay to see what happens. Thanks for your help,

Dave